# Flask - Email. Не авторизовывается для отправки Email-а

Tags: python, flask

```
app.config['MAIL_SERVER'] = 'smtp.gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 587
app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = True
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = 'Мой никнейм'
app.config['MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER'] = 'Моя Почта'   
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = 'Мой пароль'  

mail = Mail(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/sendmessage', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def sendmessage():
    msg = Message('Hello',
                  sender = 'yellowdollar55@gmail.com',
                  recipients = ['marokko6702@gmail.com']
                  )
    mail.send(msg)


app.run(host = '0.0.0.0')
```

Выдает ошибку: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials 5-20020a05600c230500b003fc01f7a42dsm8981160wmo.8 - gsmtp'). Данные USERNAME, PASSWORD, Email были введены правильно